# Does Earth's core have a heat sink and does it need one?

Tags: thermodynamics, earth, heat-conduction

Pardon a question from a complete physics noob. I know only very basic thermodynamics and if my question is completely ridiculous, I apologize.

I've heard a very interesting, yet very questionable "theory" (not official, more like an idea) that the Earth actually uses crude oil as a heat sink, in an analogy to heat engine. Thus oil extraction leads to insufficient cooling, and global warming as a result.

While, the theory can be completely bogus, and I'm not thinking that it's that easy to pinpoint the cause of global warming (there are multiple reasons AFAIK), I thought that the idea is somewhat interesting and terrifying at the same time, reminding me of Superman's Krypton.

That's why I wanted to ask people who are better at physics than I am to provide some informed feedback on this, as far as humanity aware of Earth's processes. I understand that our knowledge can be limited, especially mine. And damn, if it's not complete bogus, I better share the idea with the world :)

Still, I hope to be disproved, and the idea to belong to the realm of flat Earth. Would love to hear what people think about it, and if there is any research that can be relevant to this in any way.

Comment: That is not a theory but a lot of hot air. It's not for anyone to disapprove absurd hypothesis, but to those people with absurd claims to back them by showing how it explains commonly known facts and observation. Ask him how he explains tele- seismic data

Comment: Such pseudoscience theories are all attributed to some vague and unknown authority. To have any credence cite some published theory in a peer-reviewed journal, not some malarkey in a web post.

Comment: Sorry, but debunking stuff like that is off-topic here. But consider: fossil fuels are in the crust, and the crust is relatively thin compared to the radius of the Earth. It's a long way down, through a lot of magma, before you get to the core.

Comment: I completely agree, and I don't want to fall into the category of people who fall for all sorts of lunacy. Yet, this is the area my knowledge is currently lacking, and this theory sounded a little more sane than the usual nonsense, so I wanted to make it a learning opportunity, and study what research we have available on the matter.

Comment: Yes it has a heat sink - heat diffuses up to the surface and gets radiated out to space. We don't notice it much since the sun tends to override the thermal flux out of the surface from the interior. See https://ase.tufts.edu/cosmos/view_chapter.asp?id=21&page=1

Comment: But I suppose I should mention that [Abiogenic petroleum origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abiogenic_petroleum_origin) theories have a long and colourful history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you expected, this is complete nonsense.

There are several reasons why, and here are just a few of them:

- With or without oil, there's not anywhere near enough heat coming from the core to begin with to explain the energy imbalance we're currently experiencing. There's about 0.087 watts per square meter of heat flowing from the core to the surface, and the current measured energy imbalance is almost *ten times* that value, at 0.6 watts per square meter [(source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_energy_budget).
- The oil produced in the crust is nowhere near where the heat actually is. Every bit of oil we've been able to extract is in the top few miles of the crust, and the core *starts* at around 1,800 miles below the surface.
- There's nothing particularly special about the formation of oil that makes it significantly more endothermic than other reactions like the formation of metamorphic rock. In other words, it doesn't remove heat significantly better than other components of the crust when it's formed.
- Compared to other components of the Earth's crust, oil is pretty scarce, and so doesn't remove much heat by its formation anyway.

Comment: Not to forget to compare the heat from the sun is of the order of 1000watts/metersquared , at sea level on clear days.